# Check PayPal Payment Is completed

Tags: php, paypal

I have problems to make my PayPal system payment.

**1. User add on cart the elements him want. (In this example, user select 3 items: PDF - HTML, PDF -JS and PDF -JS)**

**2. In page when appear that 3 items and button to pay (shoppingCart.php), have the next code:**

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
        <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="myEmail@domain.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">

        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="PDF - HTML">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="5">

        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="PDF - JS">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="7">

        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_3" value="PDF - CSS">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="10">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="PaymentCompleted.php">

        <input class="btn btn-primary mt-2 m-b-20 " type="submit" value="PayNow"> 
<form>
```

**3. When user completes payment, on PayPal windows, click to "Return to Shop" and go to page "PaymentCompleted.php".**

**4. On "PaymentCompleted.php" have a SQL script who add that 3 items on clientArea payments.**

---

Problem I have, are the next:
If user add that 3 items, and go to PaymentCompleted.php, SQL Script add to it ClientArea without do payment.

**How I can check if PayPal payment has been completed and else, prevent SQL Script add that items to clientArea?**

Have a good day

Comment: You need to verify with PayPal that the order has completed, by either verifying that the client completed the payment on your `PaymentCompleted.php` page, or alternatively by receiving the asynchronous `POST` from PayPal that you can set up on order completion events

Comment: Add answer with steps how do that if is possible

Comment: The scope of that is far too large I'm afraid.  There are _many_ PayPal guides online that show exactly how to achieve this.  SO is not a coding service.